# How do I pass a sample to a loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I have a keras model where each sample consists of 3 scalars and 2 matrices. One of the matrices is a mask. I need mean squared loss function that looks like (Y_hat * mask - Y)^2, where the multiplication is point wise. Each sample will have its own mask. How do I make this mask available to the loss function?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a complex loss function, why don't you apply the mask to Y_hat before sending it to the loss function? You can still read the original values out for other purposes. With two inputs you really have to use the functional api:

```py
# assuming mask is a binary array

  y_hat = f(scalars, matrix)
  y_hat_masked = y_hat * mask
  model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs = y_hat_masked, name="example")
```

If you also need the unmasked output, you can simply use multiple outputs, and only run the loss on the masked output

```
  model = keras.Model(inputs=..., outputs=[y_hat, y_hat_masked], name="example")
  model.compile(optimizer= ..., loss = [None, loss_fun])
```